# Wien bridge oscillator problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, oscillator

I am running into a problem trying to set up a Wien Bridge oscillator on a breadboard.
It works well in the simulation:

[image]

In practice, though, I get this waveform:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: The values of R4 and R5 are way too low, you are overloading the opamp.

Comment: I think something with the non-linear negative feedback. Play with R3.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to state the sensitivity of the oscilloscope.  Are we looking at volts/division, 100mV/division, what?  The waveform could be consistent with a current-limited output going into those dreadfully low-impedance resistors at R4 and R5.  The TL072 is _wimpy_ -- try 10k resistors, and adjust your capacitors to match.  Then report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of the AGC (at around +/-600mV peak) is too minute,

Try R3 = 100k.

[image]

If the output amplitude is getting much beyond 1V peak that means your AGC is ineffective.

Your RC impedances are rather low, but probably it will work due to the low output voltage (~10mA and the TL072 is capable of ~25mA typically). Better to use R4 & R5 1k and C1 & C2 10n

Answer (score 1):

One expects sine output from Wien Bridge oscillators. Try R3=22k and R1=220k. Then there's a possibility that the high amplitude gain reduction works. Now it's nearly meaningless and the amp clips.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry. It turns out the bags of resistors I bought were mislabeled and I ended up using a 10 Ω instead of a 10 kΩ resistor.

Using the correct resistor, the circuit works:

[image]

Spehro's suggestion of using a 100 kΩ resistor for R3 also helped improve the waveform:

[image]

Thanks for all your answers!